# How to delete image attached with item in listview?

Tags: c#, listview

I am working with listview in c#. An image appeared with item when it is selected using this command

```
listView1.FocusedItem.ImageIndex = 2;
```

Now , after completing operations i want to clear/delete the images with the items in listview. 
Now using the remove command i can delete it but then i will not be able to use it again.
How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Set the Large/SmallImageList to null,or clear the images in the imagelist you assigned to the listview.

Comment: but then i will not be able to use it again :S